# Can the smart contract check for transactions in the current block?

Tags: ethereum

I am basically setting up a smart contract where if a second transaction isnt in same block the first transaction should fail.

A long time ago I saw documentation which showed how to get the current state I think it called it.
Which suggested it was possible to get information such as the block ID at the time the transaction was being confirmed.

I do not have any example at the moment as I can't find any information to test which is why I am asking here.

So does anybody know a way for the contract to check if another transaction is in the current block?

Thanks alot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am basically setting up a smart contract where if a second transaction isnt in same block the first transaction should fail.

I'm uncertain what exactly it is you're trying to do but I can't imagine this is a secure operation in practice. Ultimately the second transaction will not have any way to guarantee that the first transaction is the one that *actually* ends up getting mined in that current block (it could be replaced by a replacement/cancel tx, or it could have insufficient gas price and get mined in the next block, etc).

All that being said, you can use the contract `state` to store persistent data in the contract on-chain, but that state **won't be updated until it a 'mined' contract call updates it**. In other words, you won't be able to check if a tx is in the same block, but you can check if a tx is in a previous block.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    mapping (string => blockNumber) public transactions;

    function recordMyTransaction(string memory _id) public {
        transactions[_id] = block.number;
    }

    function executeThingIfTransactionExists(string memory _id) public {
        // string comparison
        require(transactions[_id] != 0);
        // ... do the thing
    }
}
```

See [solidity 0.8.7 docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/structure-of-a-contract.html).

Otherwise, you could do something like this using an oracle. But again, no guarantee that the transaction you're looking at is the one that goes through.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for replying. I probably worded my question wrong. I am looking to check from tx A if tx B is in the same block. Tx B will fail without Tx A being mined, but currently Tx A can be mined regardless if Tx B is in the same block or not whiih I am tring to avoid.

Comment: You can check this off-chain using an RPC provider, assuming you have the transaction hash (see: https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API). TxB must be submitted after TxA has been mined and confirmed though. You can't submit them and expect them to be mined in same block.